# Jquery Javascript validation without plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have form consists of 3 input fields and corresponding span classes beside them. I'm creating a validation with only using jquery/javascript no plugins.
Is there a way where the span messages will appear if the user input invalid type of name, like if user input 123 on userName field the span that has message Invalid Username will appear? by only using classes not id's

```
<input type = 'text' class = 'inputs' id = 'userName'> <span class = 'messageSpan' id = 'userNameMessage'>Invalid Username</span><br><br>

<input type = 'text' class = 'inputs' id = 'phoneNumber'> <span  class = 'messageSpan' id = 'phoneNumberMessage'> Invalid Phone Number </span><br><br>

<input type = 'text' class = 'inputs' id = 'emailAddress'><span class = 'messageSpan' id = 'emailAddressMessage'> Invalid Email</span><br><br>"
```

Here is my code

```
 $(".messageSpan").hide();
 $(".inputs")click(function(){
 $(this).find('.messageSpan').show();
 });
```

I have tried ung .each but it only shows all the spanMessages once I clicked one field, I want something to make the spanMessage appear only by clicking the corresponding textfield.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.messageSpan').hide();
$('.inputs').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.messageSpan').show();
});
```

`find` searches all descendants. `input` is an empty node (no children). Your spans are siblings of the inputs, not children. `next` will select the immediate sibling to the right of the element.

See [jQuery next](https://api.jquery.com/next/).

Here's an alternative solution which requires changing your HTML.

Setup containers for each input, span pair.

```
<div class='validate'>
    <input type='text' /><span>Invalid Username</span>
</div>
<div class='validate'>
    <input type='text' /><span>Invalid Phone Number</span>
</div>
<div class='validate'>
    <input type='text' /><span>Invalid Email</span>
</div>
```

Then:

```
$('div.validate > span').hide();
$('div.validate > input').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('span').show();
});
```

Comment: Wow dude, srsly, I've been looking for this answer like 2hrs now.
Since I don't want to use lots of codes referring by their id's just to show that messageSpan. very well, Thank you! I'll be back to accept the answer .